# Batch: loading bar won't work

Tags: batch-file, cmd, loading

I have a basic loading bar done but I cant think of how to have the side not move with the loading bar. Here's my code:

```
@echo off
title Loading... 
color 0a
set max=11
set num=%~1
set load=
set/a loadnum=0
:Loading
set load=%load%²
set loadnum1=%loadnum1%
cls
echo                                           Loading ""
echo                                         ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo                                         º%load%%loadnum1%           º
echo                                         ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
set/a loadnum1=%loadnum1% -1
if %loadnum%==16 goto done
goto Loading
:done
cls
timeout 1 >nul
title
color 49
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Comment: What do you mean by "side not move with the loading bar"?  Can you clarify what you see, and what you want to see?

Comment: I meant the º or the line connecting the top and bottom of the menu moves with the character that represents the bar.

Comment: Please note that `DOS` is an Operating System from the 80s/90s! Please use the tag Windows instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a variable number of trailing spaces. Keeping more or less with what you had... here is one way to do it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Loading... 
color 0a
set max=19
set load=
set /a loadnum=0
set /a loadnum1=0
set "spaces=                    "
:Loading
set load=%load%²
set /a numspaces=%max%-1+%loadnum1%
set "displayspaces=!spaces:~0,%numspaces%!
set loadnum1=%loadnum1%
cls
echo                                           Loading ""
echo                                         ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo                                         º%load%%displayspaces%º
echo                                         ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /a loadnum+=1
set /a loadnum1+=-1
if %loadnum% LSS %max% goto :Loading
endlocal
```

Comment: Originally I had a FOR loop for calculating the number of trailing spaces. I got rid of that.

Comment: Thanks I roughly knew what to do. Its not here but I made a variable (%spaces%) which was a parallel to your %displayspaces% but I couldn't figure out how to regulate the spaces between them. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution is easier to modify the wide of the load bar changing just one number; it also minimize the flicker on the screen enclosing the output commands in a code block that execute faster than individual lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set max=16

title Loading... 
color 0a
set "top=É"
set "spaces="
set "bottom=È"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%max%) do (
   set "top=!top!Í"
   set "spaces=!spaces! "
   set "bottom=!bottom!Í"
)
set "top=!top!»"
set "bottom=!bottom!¼"

set /A loadnum=0, loadNum1=max-1
set "load="

:Loading
set "load=%load%²"
(
cls
echo                                           Loading ""
echo                                         %top%
echo                                         º%load%!spaces:~0,%loadnum1%!º
echo                                         %bottom%
)
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /A loadnum+=1, loadnum1-=1
if %loadnum% lss %max% goto Loading

cls
timeout 1 >nul
title
color
```